# Can anyone tell a subquery of finding difference of 2 fields in 2 different tables as a single value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tried the below and i am able to get the answer but i need to call this as single query in front end, so can any one an alternative for this.

I don't need this as an SP:

```
DECLARE @ven INT; Declare @dai int;

select @ven= SUM(po) from Vendortable where VendorName ='HP' and Date  = '2014-01-22'

select @dai= SUM(completepo) from Daily_Volume_Tracker where AccountVendorName = 'HP' and date > = '2014-01-22'

  select @ven - @dai
```

Result:

```
Result
--------
5831
```

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head, something like this might work:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   select
   (select SUM(po) from Vendortable where VendorName ='HP' and Date  = '2014-01-22') as Val1
   ,(select SUM(completepo) from Daily_Volume_Tracker where AccountVendorName = 'HP' and date > = '2014-01-22' as Val2
)

Select Val1 - Val2 From CTE
```

I love using common table expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple subquery

```
Select 
(
    (
        select SUM(po) as Ven from Vendortable where VendorName ='HP' and Date  = '2014-01-22'
    )
    -
    (
        select SUM(completepo) as Dai from Daily_Volume_Tracker where AccountVendorName = 'HP' and date > = '2014-01-22'
    )
) Result
```